# for/in loop decrement javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to decrement a for/in loop in js.

I have found lots of instruction on decrementing a for-loop, but had no luck finding a statement that decrements a for/in loop.

```js
var classRegister = ["Lawrence", "John", "Jeff", "Bobbi"];
for( var index in classRegister ) { 
 console.log(classRegister[index]);
}
```

This is my incrementing for/in loop statement that I want to modify to decrement.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/476

Comment: Yea, it IS a bad idea to do this.  Alas I do see people who DO do this.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The discussion in your link was very helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use basic `for` loop & avoid `for..in` to iterate an array

```js
var classRegister = ["Lawrence", "John", "Jeff", "Bobbi"];
for (let i = classRegister.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(classRegister[i]);
}
```

Comment: note, due to the falsy you can just use `i` instead of `i >= 0`

Comment: It's not what I was hoping for. But it'll work. Thank you!

Comment: Yet  that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use for/in you can, you simply need to subtract your index from the last index value.

```
var classRegister = ["Lawrence", "John", "Jeff", "Bobbi"];
for( var index in classRegister ) { 
 console.log(classRegister[classRegister.length - 1 - index]);
}
```

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in

Comment: The question was simply HOW to do it in a for/in loop, not if there was a better way.

Comment: This does answer the question, but no-one is saying it is the right thing to do. :)k

Comment: Thank you Ralph. It looks like a solution that works around the limitation of for/in loops in js. Your answer as well as the other ones really help my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use [**for..in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) for arrays instead use simple loop

```js
var classRegister = ["Lawrence", "John", "Jeff", "Bobbi"];
for(let index = classRegister.length-1; index >= 0; index-- ) { 
 console.log(classRegister[index]);
}
```

Or a while loop

```js
var classRegister = ["Lawrence", "John", "Jeff", "Bobbi"];
let index = classRegister.length-1;

while(index >= 0) { 
 console.log(classRegister[index]);
 index--;
}
```

There are hacky ways to do but you should never use them IMO

```js
var classRegister = ["Lawrence", "John", "Jeff", "Bobbi"];

let copy = [...classRegister].reverse()  // this reverse array in place

for( var index in copy ) { 
 console.log(copy[index]);
}
```

Comment: If you are going to do it this way you need to reverse a copy of the array, otherwise it destructs the array order.

Comment: @RalphRitoch yeah you're right, changed to incorporate this too

Comment: `while(index)` is functionally the same as `while(index >= 0)`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no it is not, `index>=0` will not take you out of while loop at `index = 0` on the other hand `while(index)` will take you out of while loop at `index = 0`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss `while(index)` and `while(index > 0 )` will be same in functionality not `while(index >= 0)`

Comment: Yea, you are right, my brain is asleep on that BUT consider `while(index--)` and avoid that `index--;` in the while... I think my brain is 'falsey" tonight also :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes that can be done, but i prefer this for sake of readality so you can easily see `oh this while loop run untill the value is greater than 0`, this  line is `I think my brain is 'falsey" tonight also :)` awesome pun intended

Comment: In older browsers (way older) the negative while is faster than a for loop, it is able to short cycle, in newer ones that has gone away for the most part.. But I digress here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191775/discussion-between-code-maniac-and-mark-schultheiss).

Comment: Thank you all. I have very interesting options to play with now.

Comment: @BobbiLusic yes you can try things to learn, but as well as have a habit to follow good patterns so your code becomes better,readable and maintainable